# Magento 2 secret key problem

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, controllers, ajax

I've a form that performs an Ajax call to a controller, but the response always is `You entered an invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.`

> PereiraTech/Faturamento/Controller/Adminhtml/Ac/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace PereiraTech\Faturamento\Controller\Adminhtml\Ac;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory 
        )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['a' => 'b']);
        //return 'test string';
    }

    public function indexAction(){

        //echo 'test string';
    }
}
```

> PereiraTech/Faturamento/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/options.js

```
define([      
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry',  
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({


    action: function(){            
            var ajaxRequest;
            var param = 'ajax=1';
            ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({                
                url: "http://localhost/magento/admin_ptech/faturamento_fat/ac/index",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {param, form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                dataType: 'json'
            });
                //Show successfully for submit message
            ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(response);
            });

                //On failure of request this function will be called
            ajaxRequest.fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                //show error
                console.log('rou');
            });
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

> routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="faturamento_fat" frontName="faturamento_fat">
            <module name="PereiraTech_Faturamento"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

If I call just `/faturamento_fat/ac/index/` I receive the dashboard html, so I've put the full url to post method.

**Edit:** If I change from GET to POST, the returned value is a 500 Internal server error problem

Comment: did you try `/admin_ptech//faturamento_fat/ac/index` ?

Comment: @magefms Yes, it returns 404 because the post url became localhost/admin_ptech/faturamento_fat/ac/index

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the type of the request, changing for POST action I was receiving 500 Internal error server, debugging this, I found that the problem was in the PHP file:

This line

> $this->resultFactory = $resultJsonFactory;

Should be

> $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;

Comment: Did you figure it out why is not working when you use GET?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample admin ajax sample extension for you.

Link >> https://github.com/magento1993/adiminajax

Also, you can upload your extension in git so I can check and solve.

Comment: If you could take a look at my code, here's the source
https://github.com/murilopereirame/Faturamento

Comment: I am unable to understand the language which you used in extension

Comment: PHP, XML, JS. Portuguese and English

Comment: I am saying about Portuguese, other I can understand.